# How to modify output into csv from JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I found an example code to convert JSON data into CSV and I have tried to implement with a graph [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZVLJ/4/). This is the code:

```
function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel) {
    //If JSONData is not an object then JSON.parse will parse the JSON string in an Object
    var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;

    var CSV = '';    
    //Set Report title in first row or line

    CSV += ReportTitle + '\r\n\n';

    //This condition will generate the Label/Header
    if (ShowLabel) {
        var row = "";

        //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
        for (var index in arrData[0]) {

            //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
            row += index + ',';
        }

        row = row.slice(0, -1);

        //append Label row with line break
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }

    //1st loop is to extract each row
    for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
        var row = "";

        //2nd loop will extract each column and convert it in string comma-seprated
        for (var index in arrData[i]) {
            row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '"\n';
        }

        row.slice(0, row.length - 1);

        //add a line break after each row
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }

    if (CSV == '') {        
        alert("Invalid data");
        return;
    }   

    //Generate a file name
    var fileName = "DataOfficial_";
    //this will remove the blank-spaces from the title and replace it with an underscore
    fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g,"_");   

    //Initialize file format you want csv or xls
    var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);

    // Now the little tricky part.
    // you can use either>> window.open(uri);
    // but this will not work in some browsers
    // or you will not get the correct file extension    

    //this trick will generate a temp <a /> tag
    var link = document.createElement("a");    
    link.href = uri;

    //set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
    link.style = "visibility:hidden";
    link.download = fileName + ".csv";

    //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

But in the CSV file it's not what I want to get. The file contains, the values in a row, like this:

```
2012-06-26,1271000,1138683600000,1271000,1141102800000,1271000,1143781200000,0,1146369600000,0,1149048000000,0,1151640000000,0,1154318400000,0,1156996800000,0,1159588800000,3899486,1162270800000,3899486,1164862800000,3899486,1167541200000,3564700,1170219600000,3564700,1172638800000,3564700,1175313600000,2648493,1177905600000,2648493,1180584000000,2648493,1183176000000,2522993,1185854400000,2522993,1188532800000,2522993,1191124800000,2906501,1193803200000,2906501,1196398800000,2906501,1199077200000,2206761,1201755600000,2206761,1204261200000,2206761,1206936000000,2287726,1209528000000,2287726,1212206400000,2287726,1214798400000,2732646,1217476800000,2732646,1220155200000,2732646,1222747200000,2599196,1225425600000,2599196,1228021200000,2599196,1230699600000,1924387,1233378000000,1924387,1235797200000,1924387,1238472000000,1756311,1241064000000,1756311,1243742400000,1756311,1246334400000,1743470,1249012800000,1743470,1251691200000,1743470,1254283200000,1519010,1256961600000,1519010,1259557200000,1519010,1262235600000,1591444,1264914000000,1591444,1267333200000,1591444,1270008000000,1543784,1272600000000,1543784,1275278400000,1543784,1277870400000,1309915,1280548800000,1309915,1283227200000,1309915,1285819200000,1331875,1288497600000,1331875,1291093200000,1331875,1293771600000,1331875,1296450000000,1154695,1298869200000,1154695,1301544000000,1194025,1304136000000,1194025,1306814400000,1194025,1309406400000,1194025,1312084800000,1194025,1314763200000,1244525,1317355200000,475000,1320033600000,475000,1322629200000,475000,1325307600000,690033,1327986000000,690033,1330491600000,690033,1333166400000,514733,1335758400000,514733
```

I want to get data in CSV like the table [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZVLJ/4/). How can I do that?

Comment: I don't see how you're getting that from the code you wrote. Your inner loop puts double quotes around each element, and then adds a newline. Where are those characters in your file?

Comment: `row.slice()` makes no sense. `slice` is an array method, but `row` is a string. I think you mean `row = row.substr(0, row.length-1);`.

Comment: i just found in here http://jsfiddle.net/hybrid13i/JXrwM/,, what you mean in "Where are those characters in your file?" file in csv or javascript ?

Comment: @Barmar, slice is a legitimate function on the String prototype. See the documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: I'm talking about the sample row you posted at the end of the question. Is that the whole file?

Comment: @redbmk Thanks for the pointer. But you still have to assign the result. Strings are immutable in JS.

Comment: no, it's i put in same file the code, i thing it's json data format

Comment: It looks like the function is treating everything in your JSON array as the header line. The function you copied expects the JSON to be an array of objects. That's not what you're supplying.

Comment: I see the problem. You're creating the CSV from `testdata`. You should be creating it from `testdata.values`.

Comment: so, what i must modifying the data format or modifying the code ? i just tried modifying the code, but still not working

Comment: Actually, you need to create a separate CSV for each `testdata[i].values`.

Comment: where i put testdata[i].values in listing code ? because i try to put whene call the function, still not work :(

Comment: @Barmar, oh, yeah I didn't notice that line. I just saw the `row = row.slice(0, -1);` line somewhat above it.